# CouchDB - Querying array key value for first key element only

Tags: view, couchdb

I have a couchdb view set up using an array key value, in the format:

```
[articleId, -timestamp]
```

I want to query for all entries with the same article id. All timestamps are acceptable.

Right now I am using a query like this:

```
?startkey=["A697CA3027682D5JSSC",-9999999999999]&endkey=["A697CA3027682D5JSSC",0]
```

but I would like something a bit simpler.

Is there an easy way to completely wildcard the second key element? What would be the simplest syntax for this?

Comment: I believe all you need to do is `?startkey=["A697CA3027682D5JSSC"]&endkey=["A697CA3027682D5JSSC",{}]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, as a comment pointed out, there is indeed a special value `{}` that is ordered after any value, so your query becomes:

```
startkey=["target ID"]&endkey=["target ID",{}]
```

This is as equivalent to a wildcard match.

As a side note, there is no need to reverse the ordering in the map function by emitting a negative timestamp, you can reverse the order as an option to the view invocation (your start and end key will be swapped).

```
startkey=["target ID",{}]&endkey=["target ID"]&descending=true
```

Comment: Excellent. I was searching all over for this, but I guess my terminology was not exact. Thanks very much :)

Comment: Where did you find this? it works great but I was scouring documentation for the last week and this is the first place I have seen the {} mentioned.

Comment: @MBillau it's been too long, so I don't remember anymore. I think it had something to do with alphabetical ordering of `{}`.

Comment: @MBillau Docs link: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/collation.html

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, in CouchDB 3 you can use `"\ufff0"` instead of `{}`, which would be ordered after a string or number, but before an object.

From the [CouchDB 3 docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/ddocs/views/collation.html):

> Beware that {} is no longer a suitable “high” key sentinel value. Use a string like "\ufff0" instead.

> The query startkey=["foo"]&endkey=["foo",{}] will match most array keys with “foo” in the first element, such as ["foo","bar"] and ["foo",["bar","baz"]]. However it will not match ["foo",{"an":"object"}]