# CouchDB Ranking

Tags: couchdb, ranking, nosql

I'm trying to figure out the best way of sorting by rank using couch db. I have my documents setup in a players db like so:

```
{
   "_id": "user2",
   "_rev": "31-65e0e5bb1eba8d6a882aad29b63615a7",
   "username": "testName",
   "apps": {
       "app1": {
           "score": 1000
       },
       "app2": {
           "score": 1000
       },
       "app3": {
           "score": 1000
       }
   }
}
```

The player can have multiple scores for various apps. I'm trying to figure out the best way to pull say the top 50 scores for app1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one idea could be to store the score of each user for each app seperately. Like so: -

`{"app":"app1","user":"user_id","score":"9000"}`

The you could write a map function

`emit([doc.app,doc.score],{_id:doc.user,score:doc.score})`

and query the view like

`/view_name?include_docs=true&startkey=["app1",{}]&endkey=["app1"]&descending=true`

With this arrangement you have a view sorted by the score and the name of the app. Here are the results that you get.

`{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[`

`{"id":"61181c784df9e2db5cbb7837903b63f5","key":["app1",10000],"value":`

`{"_id":"5002539daa85a05d3fab16158a7861c1","score":10000},"doc":`
  `{"_id":"5002539daa85a05d3fab16158a7861c1","_rev":"1-8441f2f5dbaaf22add8969cea5d83e1b","user":"jiwan"}}`,

`{"id":"7f5d53b2da8ae3bea8e2b7ec74020526","key":["app1",9000],"value":`

`{"_id":"336c2619b052b04992947976095f56b0","score":9000},"doc":`
    `{"_id":"336c2619b052b04992947976095f56b0","_rev":"3-3e4121c1831d7ecafc056e71a2502f3a","user":"akshat"}}
]}`

You have score in value. User in doc.

**Edit**

Oops! I mistyped the `startkey` and `endkey` :) Notice that it is not `startKey` but `startkey` same for `endkey`. Also note that since descending is true we reverse the order of keys. It should work as expected now.

For more help check out

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687297/couchdb-search-or-filtering-on-key-array) and
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623154/couchdb-querying-array-key-value-for-first-key-element-only)

Comment: Thanks so much this was a huge help. I wasn't able to get your url working as it would add all the documents and not just app1 documents. So I removed the startkey and endkey and replaced it with just key and that did the trick.

/view_name?key="app1"&descending=true

Comment: Hey Dave that was a typo in my answer. Sorry about that :) check my edited answer the key ranges should be working now.

Comment: Thanks a ton I was able to get everything working. I just started using couchdb yesterday and swtiching from mysql I was loosing my mind. Your post made it a lot easier to kind of tie everything I read online to actual code. I now have a much better understanding of views, key=>value etc etc.

Comment: Glad I could help :) And considering you started couchdb just yesterday I think you have covered lot's of ground. Hope your time with couchdb is relaxing! (could not help myself there ha ha)